# How to Enable HTTPS in IIS using C#?

Tags: c#, iis, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed

Programmatically (C#) I want to configure IIS site in https. I have created a self-signing certificate and manually configured the site. But I want to automate this process using C#. I can't find a proper solution anywhere. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524896(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I know how to create\confiugre a site in IIS programmatically. But I want to configure a secured site (https) with my self-signed certificate. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Several approaches might work, calling a PowerShell script from C#, calling `Microsoft.Web.Administration`. So it is still you who should learn from a search engine like Google. How-to/tutorials are off topic here.

Comment: Running PowerShell script is possible only in PowerShell installed machines. So that I am looking for C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. This is the code i wanted.

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
Site mySite = serverManager.Sites.Add(siteName.ToString(), "http", "*:80:" + domainName, physicalPath);

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);                
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);                
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("SSL server certificate", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);                
store.Add(certificate);      

var binding = mySite.Bindings.Add("*:443:" + domainName, certificate.GetCertHash(), "My");                
binding.Protocol = "https";                
mySite.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = siteName;                
serverManager.CommitChanges();                
store.Close();
```